# Can i use the demo examples of dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS in real practice?

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I wanna try to use my software, which is based on `demo_flight_control` example of `dji_sdk_ROS` [demo_flight_control](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/blob/3.7/dji_sdk_demo/src/demo_flight_control.cpp).

In order to move the drone, a function call `setTarget` is used. To verify that the drone will arrive in the correct position specified by `setTarget` function, there are some bounds control for x,y,z.
In the demo code the bounds are 50 centimeters for x,y and z. So, if the drone is within 50 centimeters of the three directions x,y,z then it reached the correct final position.

My question regards these bounds: are they big enough for controlling the drone in real life?

My drone is dji matrice 100 with normal gps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it shoud be fine. The bounds are there for the drone to reduce the speed of the drone as it gets close to the target. I'm not sure what kind of control strategy the M100 uses, but if you test it in the simulator you'll notice that as you increase the speed of the drone, there's an increase in the overshoot before it settles at the target position. (I've also found the final position to be not that accurate and you might need some to implement a method for accurate position control).

I've adapted the same function in my program with the same 50cm boundary and it seems to work well enough.

**EDIT:**

It's been a while since I looked at the examples but if I remember correctly, the local cartesian position is computed from the GPS sensor updates. The GPS position itself is fused with with IMU sensor measurements but I digress. You calculate the local position from the GPS positions from a function provided which gives you the position offset from your target to the drone. **Depending on your control flags, (I use horizontal and vertical velocity in the ground frame)**, You apply control velocities to the drone and constantly check if its position is near the target position, if it isn't you compute the offset again and apply velocities continuosly. The boundary check is there for you to stop the drone as soon as you're close enogh to the target position. If you look at the example code, you'll notice that a 0 velocity is published to all the axes of the control publisher.

Comment: ok, perfect. I have another question, i don't understand how the drone effectively move itself, is it use gps or something else to calculate the positions? 
Because in the example for each step of the mission it first updates the current local position and the current gps position.

Comment: @PaoloMilini , I expanded on my answer

Comment: So when it reaches the target, it updates the 2 positions and if the next target is set to (0,5,0,0) the drone will be move on y for 5 units (the 5 represents the offset between its local position and the target), is it correct?  

But, if i update the local position and the gps only at the beginning (after the take off), when it reaches the first target, if i want to send it to another target and i use (0,5,0,0) it will not go to the correct position, because it calculates the offset from the initial position and not from the first target, correct?

Comment: So if i have to send target i have to calculate the offsets from the initial position? Since i'm not updating the local and gps positions, can this be a problem in real world? During simulation everything is working correctely